# How to put scanner input into an array in Java?

Tags: java

I need to ask the user for input and then put that input into a new array object and use the parcelCount variable to keep track of whats being put into the array. But my code isn't working, what am I doing wrong here?

Heres my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParcelPostSystem
{
// create a Scanner
private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

This is where I have declared my array and count variable.

```
// declare Parcel array and parcel count variable
private static Parcel[] parcels = new Parcel[10];
private static int parcelCount = 0;
```

My main method-

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

  String selection;

  do
  {

     // display menu options
     System.out.println("   ***** Parcel Post System Menu *****");
     System.out.println("A. Add New Parcel");
     System.out.println("B. Display All Parcels");
     System.out.println("C. View Delivery Details");
     System.out.println("D. Select Satchel");
     System.out.println("E. Update Tracking History");
     System.out.println("F. Complete Delivery");
     System.out.println("X. Exit the program");
     System.out.println();

     // prompt user to enter selection
     System.out.print("Enter selection: ");
     selection = sc.nextLine();

     System.out.println();



 private static void addNewParcel()
 {
  System.out.println("Add New Parcel Feature");
  System.out.println();

  //ask the user and 
  System.out.print("Enter Parcel Number: ");
  String parcelNumber = sc.nextLine();
```

Here I have attempted to create the new array object for the input but it doesn't seem to work.

```
  parcels[0] = new Parcel(parcelNumber);

  parcelCount ++;
```

Comment: Well, you seem to always put it to index 0, so next time you call that you only replace it.

Comment: Next time, please try to provide minimal but working code. "Working" in the sense of: The compiler does not reject it. One main advantage would be: We could debug your code easily.

Comment: Definitely. For example the lack of closing brackets and stuff cut in the middle. It is like saying half a sentence and expecting someone to understand whole.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this code, it should be something you want:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    // create a Scanner
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    // declare Parcel array and parcel count variable
    private static Parcel[] parcels = new Parcel[10];
    private static int parcelCount = 0;
    private static int loopCount = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String selection;
        do {
            // display menu options
            System.out.println("   ***** Parcel Post System Menu *****");
            System.out.println("A. Add New Parcel");
            System.out.println("B. Display All Parcels");
            System.out.println("C. View Delivery Details");
            System.out.println("D. Select Satchel");
            System.out.println("E. Update Tracking History");
            System.out.println("F. Complete Delivery");
            System.out.println("X. Exit the program");
            System.out.println();

            // prompt user to enter selection
            System.out.print("Enter selection: ");
            selection = sc.nextLine();

            switch (selection){
                case "A":
                    addNewParcel();
                    break;
                case "B":
                    displayAll();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Finish!");
            }

            System.out.println();
            loopCount++;
        } while (loopCount < 10);
    }

    private static void addNewParcel() {
        System.out.println("Add New Parcel Feature");
        //ask the user and
        System.out.print("Enter Parcel Number: ");
        String parcelNumber = sc.nextLine();
        parcels[parcelCount] = new Parcel(Integer.valueOf(parcelNumber));
        parcelCount++;
    }

    private static void displayAll() {
        System.out.println("parcels:");
        for (int i = 0; i < parcels.length; i++) {
            if(null != parcels[i]) {
                System.out.println(parcels[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Parcel {
    private int number;

    public Parcel(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "parcel: " + String.valueOf(number);
    }
}
```

And here is an output:

```
   ***** Parcel Post System Menu *****
A. Add New Parcel
B. Display All Parcels
C. View Delivery Details
D. Select Satchel
E. Update Tracking History
F. Complete Delivery
X. Exit the program

Enter selection: A
Add New Parcel Feature
Enter Parcel Number: 99

   ***** Parcel Post System Menu *****
A. Add New Parcel
B. Display All Parcels
C. View Delivery Details
D. Select Satchel
E. Update Tracking History
F. Complete Delivery
X. Exit the program

Enter selection: A
Add New Parcel Feature
Enter Parcel Number: 88

   ***** Parcel Post System Menu *****
A. Add New Parcel
B. Display All Parcels
C. View Delivery Details
D. Select Satchel
E. Update Tracking History
F. Complete Delivery
X. Exit the program

Enter selection: B
parcels:
parcel: 99
parcel: 88
```